Most efficent way to find all rows where row value is X2 greater than or equal to the previous two rows combine
In this scenario, I'll have a table that has column that is Fruit, this column will have about 1000 + distinct entries in it an a entry on a per day basis.   What I'm trying to do is for each distinct type of Fruit, I want to find where the day has sold 2x the amount of fruit from the previous two days combined.
So for example, if on day 1&2, there was 1 apple sold each day I would have a total of 2 sold, I want to know whenever the following day has sold 2x the previous, so if day 3 has 4 apples sold then this is a positive result, however if 3 were sold, then this would be a negative result.  I've put together a very clunky and slow cursor that I'm not confident in the results.  One of the things to take into consideration is the data always need to be ordered by date desc, sometime the data isn't populated everyday an the ID will be out of order.
Here is a test query that has the final results I'm looking for.
declare @testTable table(Id int not null identity(1,1),Fruit nvarchar(10),Sold int, DateSold date)

DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2024-01-22';
DECLARE @EndDate   datetime = Dateadd(day,100,@StartDate);

WITH theDates AS
     (SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
        FROM theDates
       WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
     )
     insert into @testTable(Fruit,Sold,DateSold)
SELECT 'Apple',90+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY theDate),theDate as theValue
  FROM theDates
  union 
  SELECT 'Orange',90+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY theDate),theDate as theValue
  FROM theDates
    union 
  SELECT 'Pears',90+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY theDate),theDate as theValue
  FROM theDates
    union 
  SELECT 'Plums',90+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY theDate),theDate as theValue
  FROM theDates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

Fiddle with sample data:

https://dbfiddle.uk/coq20xzk

declare @appleRow int = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @testTable where fruit = 'Apple' ORDER BY NEWID());
declare @ornageRow int = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @testTable where fruit = 'Orange' ORDER BY NEWID());
declare @pearRow int = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @testTable where fruit = 'Pears' ORDER BY NEWID());
declare @plumRow int = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @testTable where fruit = 'Plums' ORDER BY NEWID());

update @testTable
set Sold = Sold + 250
where Id in (@appleRow,@ornageRow,@pearRow,@plumRow);

select * from @testTable;

--these are the ids am looking for
select * from @testTable
where Id in (@appleRow,@ornageRow,@pearRow,@plumRow);


The key here will be the LAG() window function.
Try this:
WITH lags AS (
    select Fruit, DateSold, Sold
        ,Lag(Sold, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Fruit ORDER BY DateSold) YesterdaySold
        ,Lag(Sold, 2, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Fruit ORDER BY DateSold) DayBeforeSold
    from TestTable
)
SELECT * 
FROM lags
WHERE Sold >= 2 * (YesterdaySold + DayBeforeSold);

See it here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/yGw6WhmM


Should it not be Sold >= 2 * .... as the requirement is "find where the day has sold 2x the amount of fruit from the previous two days combined"?

@Alex - it's fine I should have done a better job in the title

Joel, it's not intitive and I've read it about 10 times and still it doesn't make sense to me, but DateSold has to be ordered asc for the previous days

I fixed the ordering (and the >= while I was at it)

I would use the moving window technique. Expanding on your original fiddle:
select sq.*
from (
    select t.*,
        isnull(sum(t.Sold) over(
            partition by t.Fruit
            order by t.DateSold
            -- Moving window: 2 rows before the current
            rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding
        ), 0) as [Prev2DaysSale]
    from testTable t
) sq
where sq.Sold > 2 * sq.Prev2DaysSale
order by sq.Fruit, sq.DateSold;

One caveat, however: this query calculates previous sale amount for 2 previous records, not 2 previous dates. If you have gaps in your records, you'll need to somehow introduce the records for missing dates with zero sale amounts. That's assuming you need "2 previous dates" exactly, of course.

Should it not be Sold >= 2 * .... as the requirement is "find where the day has sold 2x the amount of fruit from the previous two days combined"?

@Alex, up to OP. The question is a bit ambiguous in this regard, as its title contradicts the detailed explanation. I suppose anyone can turn greater into greater or equal without much trouble.

@RogerWolf something really odd is happening in my real table which has about 2mil + rows.  If you add and sq.Prev2DaysSale >0  to elimite the first day, the query never finishes.   If you don't have that in the where clause it's about 15 seconds.  I'm probably going to add row over to elimite the first row but just thought it was odd.   If you're curious as to why I would eliminate the first row, it's because there has to be a sale, if nothing exists before the first day, there obviously wasn't a sale.

@user1257758, some quirk of the query optimiser. Try to remove the isnull() - it will exclude rows with no previous sales. Also, try to enable the actual execution plan for the query and check if SSMS recommends any indices - if it doesn't suggest including half the table, you may try that as well.

In the example, an index similar to (Fruit, DateSold) include (Sold) should make the most sense.
